# How to connect Laptop's USB to TV's RCA Inputs?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, usb, display

How to connect Laptop's USB to TV's RCA Inputs?

can you provide what is the setting in need to change on windows

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense.  USB Carries data. RCA Inputs are for video (yellow) or audio (red and white).

Comment: What you need is a VGA (blue 15 pin trapezoid) to RCA adaptor. I haven't priced them recently but they used to run around $100.

Comment: Don’t forget the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menns is right. You cant go straight from USB to RCA. You need something in between to convert the signal.